# In SOLR, how to fq(filter query) for two different fields?

Tags: solr

I need the Filter Query to satisfy two different conditions on separate field.

I tried the following and none worked

fq="color:red AND type:book"

fq="+color:red +type:book"

I cannot use two different fq as thats the limitation set by the SOLRPHP lib I am using which requests $param["fq"] as a single argument. Therefore I need to pass one query to this function.

I am new to Solr so please dont mind if I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Try `fq:(color:red AND type:book)` or `fq:(+color:red +type:book)`. By using quotes around your criteria, you are telling Solr to execute a phrase query, so it is not recognizing the field names within the phrase.

Answer (score 1):

You may be encountering a question with the SolrPHP API.

With SolrJ, for instance, its beneficial to pass the fq like this query.set("fq", "fieldName:" + "\"" + fieldValue + "\""); Note the escaped quotes around the query value.

You may want to review the wiki or ask your question in the Solr PHP discussion group https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/php-solr-client